# Can GPS time be obtained from the DJI Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I've looked through the DJI Windows SDK API, but there doesn't appear to be a way to retrieve the GPS time.  Is this a missing capability?

Answer (score 0):

I agree; there doesn't seem to be an API call for this.

Which seems weird.

Comment: There's [this](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-time-sync.html) but I have no idea how this interacts with the Windows SDK API